# Did Punisher succeed in decreasing crime rates?

Tags: marvel, comics, the-punisher

Punisher is known for *getting the job done*, *"You hit them they get up, I hit them they stay down"*, etc.

Did Punisher factually reduce crime rates in his area/city?

Canonical references please, No numbers are needed:

A declaration of a newspaper, TV (in comics) newscast, one character dialog, one policeman commentary, storyteller text box.

Comment: Given that each of his actions were at least assault, usually aggrevated assault or murder I'd say it's probably a wash, but I don't have the numbers to back it up.

Comment: @Paul your concern was addressed in a new edited version of the question.

Comment: Probably he's doing better than Batman, who's supposed to be the world's greatest detective but Gotham has the worst crime rates in all of the world, as all of the criminal masterminds he keeps arresting (Joker, Penguin et al) keep escaping and continue to wreak havoc.

Comment: @Loki you just hit the origin of the question

Comment: @Loki There was a point I saw made at one point about Arrowverse. There was bad bad guy killing people and the good guys refused to kill him. Later, he kills more people and finally dies as a result, but the point remained that the good guys could have prevented that. Punisher arguably has something going in that he's willing to kill, while Batman is more interested in simply stopping crime without murder (for the most part)

Comment: @Machavity - That's a less reliable strategy in real life than the way it's usually presented in the comics, though. Even organized state use of force against threats (policing, war) doesn't always have the desired effect, to say nothing of vigilantism.

Comment: I can't recall any comments that would imply crime stats went down specifically tied to the Punisher's efforts. I do seem to recall comments on more than one occasion (probably from Garth Ennis' run on the character, MAX or not) from police saying something to the effect that it made little sense to spend police time and effort to catch him as he was making their jobs easier. Hardly something official, that.

Comment: @RDFozz "Making their jobs easier" Now every criminal carries heavier armaments and lives in paranoid fear of a man kicking down their door to kill them.  I'm sure that'll make arresting criminals easier.

Comment: I'm quite sure I've read somewhere people saying that yes, his efforts reduced the local crime rate; but I can't recall which arc or issue, sorry.

Answer (score 7):

It would appear not. On at least one occasion, despite his best efforts and his destruction of an entire crime family, we learn that criminality continues apace.

[image]
<sub><sup>[Daredevil vs. Punisher Vol 1 4](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Daredevil_vs._Punisher_Vol_1_4)</sup></sub>

That being said, we can only imagine [how bad things could be](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Bludhaven) had he not been present.

Comment: It's true, [we can only imagine](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elysium) what the city would look like.

Answer (score -5):

I would sincerely doubt it. Civil war(comic not the movie) it mentioned the Punisher, but eventually, he shot practically every top shot criminal that tried joining Team America. So it is possible as he practically went wild. Then again during civil war majority of criminals joined Team Iron Man so I wouldn't say it was all him.